# I would like to install SAMBA on my UBUNTU desktop

Tags: samba

I would like to install/configure SAMBA to share a Folder on my UBUNTU desktop with my Windows servers and client.

What do I need to download/configure to do this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

That will install SAMBA.  To use it, read up on

```
man samba
```

after you install it.  Alternatively

```
system-config-samba
```

will let you configure SAMBA shares.